# Изменение цифры слайда (slick)

Tags: css, slick.js

В слайдере есть 8 слайдов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при переключении слайдера менялась цифра (тоесть увеличивалась на 1). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код, который есть на данный момент.  Это можно сделать нажав на "править" под вопросом.

Comment: Не смог залить на codepen, залил весь архив на файлообменник https://ru.files.fm/u/94kywkdb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847297/slick-js-get-current-and-total-slides-ie-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.slider').on(`init reInit`, function(event, slick) {
  $('.counter').text(1 + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
})
$('.slider').on(`afterChange`, function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  $('.counter').text(currentSlide + 1 + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
})
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots: false
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slide {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 80px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:900;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, orange);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
  <div class="slide">7</div>
</div>
<div class="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не видя верстку и прикрученный код дам ответ в общем виде:

У слайдера slick.js есть события, в частности, вы можете использовать `afterChange`, которому на вход вторым аргументом передается `currentSlide`, обозначающий номер слайда. А дальше уже дело за малым — ставите это значение в нужное вам место с помощью javascript обработчика события смены слайда.